# Prevent modifications to Form.FormBorderStyle in derived class

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a base class enforce this:

```
public class DialogForm : Form 
{
    public DialogForm()
    {
        base.HelpButton = true;//enforce this
        base.MinimizeBox = false;//enforce this
        base.MaximizeBox = false;//enforce this
    }
}
```

**AND** be sure it is not modified afterwards, how can this be done ?

I cannot override the `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox` properties since they are not virtual, if someone casts `DialogForm` as `Form` will bypass the following code :

```
new public bool MinimizeBox
{
    get { return false; }
    set { base.MinimizeBox = false; }
}

new public bool MaximizeBox
{
    get { return false; }
    set { base.MaximizeBox = false; }
}
```

Thanks

---

For reference here is how to solve it (thanks to SLacks)

```
private bool m_inOnStyleChanged = false;
protected override void OnStyleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!m_inOnStyleChanged)
    {
        m_inOnStyleChanged = true;
        base.OnStyleChanged(e);
        base.HelpButton = true;
        base.MinimizeBox = false;
        base.MaximizeBox = false;
        m_inOnStyleChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also only each property if it's `true` to prevent recursion.

Comment: @SLaks : Indeed, and it would better dans using a global flag too... thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `OnStyleChanged` and set the properties to `false`.
This method is called (indirectly) by the property setters.
Note that this will not necessarily be true in future versions (although it probably will be)

You should also add

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DesignerSerializationVisiblity(DesignerSerializationVisiblity.Hidden)]
```

However, there is nothing wrong with merely hiding the properties.
You (probably) shouldn't be afraid that someone will cast your instance down to `Form` and set them.
Are your clients actually hostile?

Comment: This is only called when SetStyle is used - not sure how that helps in this scenario.

Comment: @Jeff: Wrong.  It's called by _property setter_ -> `UpdateFormStyles` -> `UpdateStyles` -> `OnStyleChanged`.  I checked the source.

Comment: @SLaks: Hmmm, that may be the case, but the docs don't back that up - and I don't see how changing the ability to maximize or minimize will result in this event.

Comment: @Jeff: If you look in the source code or Reflector, this event _will be raised_ when any of these three properties are set.

Comment: @SLaks: I don't like relying on implementation details.

Comment: @Jeff: There is no other option.

Comment: @SLaks: THere's always another option ;) See option 2 in my answer. It's not necessarily a great option, but it's an option.

Comment: @Jeff: That's not really an option.  See my comment to your answer.

Comment: @Jeff is right, these properties have nothing to do with the control styles.  The OP's code works by accident.  Overriding CreateParams is the real fix.  Not that this would slow anybody down, they can just inherit the form and override it again.

Comment: @Hans: Not if he seals it.  You're right; that would be better.  I hadn't looked that deeply.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available if you want to control whether your form has these buttons or not.

1. Hide the properties by using the `new` keyword so that your versions are seen and used (they could still use the old ones by casting to `Form`).
2. Create a new class that wraps an instance of `Form` and have people derive from that. This would require extra effort to expose all the events and calls that you want them to be able to use, but it would give you complete control over what can and cannot be done with the form.
3. Listen for the OnStyleChanged event and ensure these properties don't change. This relies on an undocumented implmentation detail so it is possible that future .NET frameworks may not behave this way.
4. Allow the buttons to appear but try to control their effects on your form. You may not be able to control whether a derivation shows or hides these buttons but you might be able to control the effect they have on your form. However, this is somewhat messy. You can probably achieve this by overriding some of the lower level methods such as [`SetBoundsCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx). You should also look at the [`MaximizedBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizedbounds.aspx) property and the associated handler [`OnMaximizedBoundsChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onmaximizedboundschanged.aspx). As minimizing results in a `Resize` event, you should be able to control that also.

Comment: I'm figuring that they can at least control what those buttons do, so that even if they do appear, they can prevent them from working. I'm still investigating the idea of not allowing those values to change.

Comment: This has nothing to do with his properties.

Comment: Yes, it does. If there's no way to override the properties, then perhaps he can override the behaviour so that his base class remains in control.

Comment: Option #2 won't be usable in a WinForms environment.  You will need the _real_ `Form` instance for a variety of reasons.  Plus, it won't even help: `someControl.FindForm().MaximizeBox = true`.

Comment: @Slaks: If you want to go to that level, then the change you suggest won't help either because someone can resort to Win32 and hack the window.

Comment: @Jeff: That requires Full Trust.  This doesn't, and is no less likely than casting to `Form`.

Comment: @SLaks: Agreed. My personal option would be to just `new` the properties. The use-cases where I can see this architecture being useful are for "bicycle lock" type re-use anyway (i.e. discouraging behaviour rather than banning it). Of course, if I was creating something for use outside my own team where there were no peer reviews to catch misuse, something more robust would be needed - but relying on the implementation (though clearly, the most robust option as it stands) is not a great plan because it can change at the whim of someone else.